# Upload file in Symfony 3.4 - Operation of update - how i should programming editAction?

Tags: php, symfony

i have a problem with my editAction(),  It looks like it the problem is with path:
"The file "G:\xampp5.6\htdocs\future\future/web/uploads/images/G:\xampp5.6\tmp\phpB0E6.tmp" does not exist"  .
I dont know what can i do.

```
    /**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing blog entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="blog_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Blog $blog)
{

    $blog->setImage(
new File($this->getParameter('image_directory').'/'.$blog->getImage()));

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($blog);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BlogType', $blog);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_edit', array('id' => $blog->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('blog/edit.html.twig', array(
        'blog' => $blog,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

EDIT:
How can I set correct paths?  Because in my database path is G:\xampp5.6\tmp\phpA7BF.tmp  and should  only name image for example fa7bcdd50522b0592c5f98ab8313041.jpeg

Comment: When are you setting `$blog::$image` ? Looks like it already contains the full path to your image

Comment: Your path seem bad `G:\xampp5.6\htdocs\future\future/web/uploads/images/G:\xampp5.6\tmp\phpB0E6.tmp`

Comment: @gogaz i know, and i dont know what can i do with this problem?

Comment: Check where you use `$blog->setImage()`. anyway the issue is not in this code snippet

Comment: @gogaz my all code : https://pastebin.com/2vqQJLjM

Comment: @gogaz i took knowledge from  https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: I see 2 possibilities. One is, in windows os, the folder separator is '\' I think. So may be you need to change the folder separator in parameter.yml. The other one is, Symfony is having some trouble with giving permission to create that file. Give write permission for that xampp5.6\tmp folder.

Comment: Ok. I took knowledge from symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html , So, how i should correct my editAction()? Really sorry but I don't understand it

Answer (score 1):

solution:

in config.yml  we have to use backslash:

```
parameters:
locale: en
image_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%\web\uploads\images'
```

BlogContoller.php

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing blog entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="blog_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Blog $blog)
{



    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($blog);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BlogType', $blog);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {


        new File($blog->getImage());

        $file=$blog->getImage();
        $fileName=md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();


        $file->move(
        $this->getParameter('image_directory'),$fileName
        );


        $blog->setImage($fileName);


        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_edit', array('id' => $blog->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('blog/edit.html.twig', array(
        'blog' => $blog,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```